# Client can't ping server untill server has first pinged client?

Tags: networking, ping

Problem:

Client computer can't ping server until the server has first pinged client. If I stop pinging the client from the server, the client will no longer be able to ping the server. Does anyone know what causes this and how to fix it?

Win7 to server 2008, firewalls off, no AV, etc.

Comment: I am experiencing the same problems in my corporate environment. i have never understood why. faulty switch (easy answer)?

Answer (score 1):

Are the systems on the same subnet?  If so, you have ARP issues.

Verify with a packet capture - you would normally see the ARP request send from the client and receive on the server, then the response send back from the server and be received by the client - but with this issue, you'll see one of these steps not happen (likely the server won't see the client's broadcast request).

The cause is likely somewhere in your network equipment/topology.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify if you PC's address was set manually or with DHCP.

If it is set manually have you set the netmask correctly?